# Is there any way to use replace method for last occuring characters in a string?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "lala";
var newStr = str.replace('l', 'm');
```

The value of newStr becomes 'mala', as the replace method finds the first occurrence of character in the string and replaces the character and then stops.

But I want the output "lama".
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for this:

```js
var str = "lala";
var newStr = str.replace(/l([^l]*)$/, 'm$1'); // lama
console.log(newStr);
```

This pattern matches an `l` followed by any number of characters that are not `l` until the end of the string. This will only match one time since the string ends only once (i.e in `"lalblc"` it matches `"lc"`). Then it replaces `"lc"` with `"m"` followed by the group of letters after the `l` (which is `"c"`). In the end, you are left with the original string but with the last `l` replaced with `m`.

`[^l]` means "any letter that is not `l`"

`*` means "any number of times (0 or more)"

The parenthesis create a capturing group which can be referenced using `$1` in the replacement.

---

If you will be doing this frequently, it would be useful to move this to a function. You can make a function, `replaceLast` that can be called on strings by doing:

```js
String.prototype.replaceLast = function (search, replace) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(search+"([^"+search+"]*)$"), replace+"$1");
}

str = "lala";
newStr = str.replaceLast("l", "m");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: this one's probably better than mine :)

Comment: Thanks! I am a beginner and I don't understand what is regex? Can you tell me about in brief, please?

Comment: @HTMLBoy I added a brief explanation. It takes practice to learn regex, but it is a very powerful tool for finding patterns in text. You can find many tutorials online and you can test some stuff out at https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You can match everything up to an "l" followed by anything that's *not* an "l":

```js
    var str = "lala";
    var newStr = str.replace(/(.*)l([^l]*)$/, "$1m$2");
    console.log(newStr);
```

The first group, `(.*)`, will consume as much of the string as it can. The second group, `([^l]*)$`, will match the rest of the source string after the last "l".

Answer (score 2):

Here i've created a custom function also i've avoided using any `regex` since it's quite difficult for any beginner to understand.

```js
var str = "lala";

const customReplace = (replaceChar, replaceWith, str) => {
  const lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(replaceChar);
  const leftPortion = str.slice(lastIndex);
  const rightPortion = str.slice(lastIndex+1);

  return `${leftPortion}${replaceWith}${rightPortion}`;
}

console.log(customReplace('l', 'm', str))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse, replace and reverse again.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a search for `l` which is not followed by optional non `l` characters and an `l`.

```js
var str = "lala",
    newStr = str.replace(/l(?![^l]*l)/, 'm');

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use Look ahead in RegEx to find the last character :

```js
var str = "lala";
var newStr = str.replace(/l(?!.*l)/, 'm');
console.log(newStr);
```

for more information you can read [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way to replace, a bit silly but it works as well

```js
var str = "lalalc";
var newStr = [...str];
newStr[str.lastIndexOf('l')] ='m';
newStr.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex to replace second occurance of letter:

```js
var str = "lala";
var newStr = str.replace(/(?<=l.*?)l/,"m"); 
console.log(newStr);
```